# Как заблокировать диапазон ip-адресов версии 6?

Tags: хостинг, ipv6, cpanel

Пользуюсь виртуальным хостингом. В панели управления хостингом cPanel заметил странные запросы на определенный URL с разных ip-адресов (порядка 8000 за день):

[image: Раздел Посетители в cPanel]

В панели управления хостингом есть Блокиратор IP:

[image: Раздел Блокиратор IP в cPanel]

Разных ip-адресов порядка 8000 каждый день, одинаковые только первые 4 цифры (например, 2a07, 2a09 и так далее). Если использую такой шаблон 2a07::/16, 2a09::/16, то ip-адреса из этого диапазона не блокируются. Как можно заблокировать диапазоны ip-адресов, которые начинаются с 2a07, 2a09 и так далее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Блокировка по шаблону 2a07::/16, 2a09::/16 проходит, возвращается HTTP-код 403. Вот мой .htaccess:

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 2a0e::/16
deny from 2a09::/16
deny from 2a07::/16
```

В разделе Посетители в сPanel теперь так:

[image: Раздел Посетители в сPanel]

Яндекс.Метрика теперь не видит этих посетителей. Вопрос решён.